# Export disqus to wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I have been using disqus for my comments system on my blog for some time now and I would like to move to another comment system and maybe even just use wordpress. Is there anyway I can copy the custom disqus XML file to a wordpress file (WXL) or something else without rewriting it or re-coding something. I am looking for a simple fix, or as simple as you can get it.
The custom disqus XML format is here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472150-custom-xml-import-format

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Disqus Comment System plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) has a synchronize feature that will allow you to move your Disqus comments into the WordPress comment system.  I'd recommend installing this plugin, configuring your credentials (to get it connected with your Disqus account) and then run their synchronization feature.

Comment: It only imported the first 10 to wordpress and when I tried to reimport it to another disqus it only imported one